# Python KafkaTimeoutError: Timeout waiting for future

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm using Kafka to send logs to a topic. While sending the messages, I always get this error

```
Message: 'test log'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/applications/pythonapp/kafka_handler.py", line 53, in emit
    self.flush(timeout=1.0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/applications/pythonapp/kafka_handler.py", line 59, in flush
    self.producer.flush(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env_revamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 649, in flush
    self._accumulator.await_flush_completion(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env_revamp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/record_accumulator.py", line 529, in await_flush_completion
    raise Errors.KafkaTimeoutError('Timeout waiting for future')
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Timeout waiting for future
```

I tried a few solutions like commenting out the line

```
self.flush(timeout=1.0)
```

I also tried increasing the timeout value to 5.0 but in vain.

My stack :

Python 3.8.10

Pip package list

```
alembic==1.8.1
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
dataclasses==0.6
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-Migrate==4.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
graypy==2.1.0
greenlet==2.0.1
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.0.0
importlib-resources==5.10.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
kafka-python==2.0.2
logging-gelf==0.0.26
Mako==1.2.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
marshmallow==3.19.0
numpy==1.24.2
packaging==21.3
pip==20.0.2
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pyparsing==3.0.9
requests==2.28.1
setuptools==44.0.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.44
urllib3==1.26.12
Werkzeug==2.2.2
zipp==3.10.0
```

Does anybody have any idea what this error is and how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same errors with acks KafkaProducer argument equals to 0 or 1. If i use acks = 'all' i have no error.

```
my stack : 
Python 3.11.7

Package      Version
------------ -------
kafka-python 2.0.2
pip          23.3.2
setuptools   69.0.2
wheel        0.42.0

kafka version 3.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing to fix this is update the library to a maintained one and adding additional fields to the config.

One thing I've noticed is that the Kafka-Python lib is no longer being maintained so I've used this lib instead.
https://github.com/wbarnha/kafka-python-ng

I would also consider updating your Python version as well, noticed some failures due to older Python versions in my Google Searches

The new lib is basically the same thing so you're config and setup will remain the same, just need to remove

`kafka-python` and Install
`kafka-python-ng`

```
            acks='all', # wait for all brokers to acknowledge broker
            retries=10, # increased retries but need to handle duplication
```

I've added retries and set ack to `all` as well.
Chances are you'll need to handle de-duplication downstream of this kafka-pipeline due to the retry logic.